# How can I append two properties together in a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I have two properties, e.g. date and number. I have a listbox that currently binds them one after the other, so now there are two lines taken up by the two properties. How can I just line them up one by one? The xaml won't let me bind two properties to one textblock.

So here's how my listbox looks right now:

Number
Date

I want it to look like:

Number Date

My listbox code looks like the following below:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,35,0,-32" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfItems}" Grid.RowSpan="3" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yy}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Run** to bind multiple properties to one textblock

```
 <TextBlock>
       <Run Text="{Binding Number}"></Run>
       <Run Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yy}}"></Run>
 </TextBlock>
```

Or **MultiBinding**

```
 <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
                <Binding Path="Number" />
                <Binding Path="Date" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works out the best. I used Run and it spaces out a single space between the two properties. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you require is to use horizontal Orientation in your StackPanel. Change your DataTemplate to the one below:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yy}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know that, how do I make a space between the Number and Date so that it's visible/clearer to read? Thanks.

Comment: Use a margin Left/Right on the TextBlock or add another TextBlock with a space as the text.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can create another property on your data that uses String.Format to concatenate into a new string, and bind to that. Also consider using @Heena Patil's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want the `StackPanel` to stack items horizontally: `Orientation="Horizontal"`.

(cfr. http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752328(v=vs.110).aspx)